# How to set an optional argument from python in terminal?

Tags: python

I have a program that takes one input but can also take another optional argument if the user wants. How can I implement this optional argument?

I am importing sys library to get the first arguement like this

```
word_input = sys.argv[1]
num_input = sys.argv[2] // I want to make this optional
```

Answer (score 2):

Test for the length; `sys.argv` is just a list, really:

```
num_input = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else None
```

Comment: That did not work, I get index out of range error              word_input = sys.argv[1]
if (len(sys.argv[1]) > 2):
        num_input = sys.argv[2]
else:
        None

Comment: @HellMan: you are testing the wrong thing; test the length of `sys.argv`, *not* `sys.argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for more dependable CLI parsing out of the box.  Arguments prepended by `--` are implicitly optional.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

gives

```
$ python myprogram.py --help
usage: myprogram.py [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --foo FOO   foo help
```